# How to get JSONObject without JSONArray

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I have such a JSON: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HkTK9xTzNx/

How do I get a "imdb_id" String (line 14). There is no array which contains that value,it's not in square branches,so I don't know how to get it.

Comment: all json file convert to a JsonObject, for exmple name parent, you must get imdb_id from this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution as per your need:

```
try {
     imdbLink = response.getString("imdb_id");
 } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

> A standard solution:

```
String json = "{\"imdb_id\":\"str12345\"}"; // your json response from network call/local file

JSONObject jsonObject;

try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

    String id = jsonObject.getString("imdb_id");

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what should be 'json' String be equal to. Here's my code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xddZX6f85g/